# How to insert term into vocabulary named Tag

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to populate nodes by writing a script...i am using following code

```
$node->field_tags['und'][0]['textfield'] = 'first_tag';
$node->field_tags['und'][0]['textarea'] = 'This is tag';
$node->field_tags['und'][0]['tid'] = 2;
node_save($node);
```

whatsits doing is nothing and the term is not being added to vocabulary named tag...if i write the following code it will select the already existed term call xml..i guess because of tid=1;

```
$node->field_tags['und'][0]['textfield'] = 'first_tag';
$node->field_tags['und'][0]['textarea'] = 'This is tag';
$node->field_tags['und'][0]['tid'] = 2;
node_save($node);
```

i even tried the following code

```
$node->field_tags['und'][0]['name'] = 'first_tag';
$node->field_tags['und'][0]['description'] = 'This is tag';
$node->field_tags['und'][0]['tid'] = 2;
node_save($node);
```

can someone please help me how add terms into a already existed vocabulary

Comment: The title of the question is asking for something, and the question is asking something else. Inserting terms into a vocabulary is different from populating nodes; actually, to insert terms into a vocabulary, you don't any node object.

Comment: actually i was explaining what i am doing..maybe i was wrong....saving the terms in the vocabulary is the part....the problem is that i know how to do it in drupal 6 but have no idea how to do it in drupal 7. someone please just guide me

Answer (score 1):

Get dynamically vid using below function

```
$vid = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('vocabname');
$terms = new stdClass();
$terms->vid = $vid; 
$terms->name='whatever name of your term'; 
taxonomy_term_save($terms);
```

Thanks,
Ankush

Answer (score 0):

got it after reading hundreds of line code

$terms =  new stdClass();
$terms->vid=1;
$terms->name='success';
$get_tid=new stdClass();

taxonomy_term_save($terms);

term will be save in vocabulary vid=1 with automatic tid....